Proof of logarithmic equality with floor and ceiling
I have to prove the following identity:
$$\left\lfloor \log _2(n)\right\rfloor\equiv\left\lceil \log _2(n+1)-1\right\rceil$$
Each side is defined for all $n>0\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, when plotting both sides, they seem to be equal:

For example, the $\left\lceil \log _2(n+1)-1\right\rceil$ side returns a very similar value for the logarithm, but as it decreases in one unit and performs ceiling, it rounds to the same integer as the floor of the logarithm. However, I can't find a way to prove it right for every valid $n$.

Here's a hint for how to get started. Start by Assuming $m = \lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor$. That is$$m \le \log_2 n < m + 1.$$You wish to show that $m = \lceil \log_2 (n + 1) - 1 \rceil$, that is$$m - 1 < \log_2(n+1) - 1 \le m.$$Can you use the former to show the latter?

Hint: For integers, the inequality $a \le b$ is equivalent to $a-1 <b$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Then there exists an integer $z\geq 0$ such that $ 2^z\leq n\leq 2^{z+1}-1<2^{z+1}.$ Then:
One the one hand, $z\leq\log _2(n)<\log_2(2^{z+1})=z+1,$ and so, $\left\lfloor \log _2(n)\right\rfloor = z.$
On the other hand, $ 2^z<2^z+1\leq n+1\leq 2^{z+1},$ and so $z<\log_2(n+1)\leq z+1.$ This implies $z-1<\log_2(n+1)-1\leq z,$ and so $\left\lceil \log_2(n+1)-1\right\rceil=z.$ Therefore, for all integers $n,$
$$\left\lfloor \log _2(n)\right\rfloor=\left\lceil \log _2(n+1)-1\right\rceil.$$
